# Factorial using Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I got a nightmare on threads on solving Factorial using multithreading I got a simple idea like why dont we use quicksort technique to solve this i am talking about divide and conquer...

for example my explanation in code format...

For suppose if i got to find factorial for 8 let us confine a parition to only 2 parts

thread1 solving factorial n to n/2

```
8*fact(7)
8*7*fact(6)
8*7*6*fact(5)
8*7*6*5*fact(4)
```

thread2 calculates `fact(4)`

now my problem i dont know how to solve is how to remove fact(4) from thread1 so that i just finish off my answer as

```
 result=thread1output*thread2output
```

Please provide code with comments please Hoping to get positive response from you..Thanks for going through till end

Comment: I don't think this is going to work like you expect with multiple threads, and without multiple threads it's [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can you please explain fastest method to solve this rather than the traditional way we do using recursion...thanks for comment

Comment: No one wants to do your homework for you.

Comment: thats not my homework thats a nightmare seriously....

Comment: Sorry, but "please write some code for me" questions are not going to work.  Irrespective of whether the task is homework or not.  However, we will answer questions about >>your<< code, and help you with problems that you have in writing it.

Comment: I dont understand how to proceed so i asked for help i am newbie in threads still learning with examples...

Comment: You learn more / better by writing code or *trying to* write code than by reading someone else's examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to attack factorial with multiple threads, you need to partition the series into units of work. With 2 threads, a simplistic approach is to divide the series in 2.

For example 8!

- thread 1 8x7x6x5
- thread 2 4x3x2x1

One way is to allocate the work in an outer method, passing the range into each thread then multiplying the result.

Actually, you can do this with the stream API:

```
long factorial = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, n).parallel().reduce((a, b) -> a * b).get();
```

This can process the calculation in parallel.

For n larger than 20, the result will exceed the largest value a `long` can hold; use `BigInteger` for the arithmetic instead:

```
BigInteger factorial = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
.parallel()
.mapToObj(String::valueOf)
.map(BigInteger::new)
.reduce((a, b) -> a.multiply(b))
.get();
```

Comment: Yes ... but this doesn't help you understand what is going on under the hood.  Or how to do it using threads directly, for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1):

A generally applicable optimization for when one computation depends on the results of a previous computation is a [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Rather then simply recursing, check if the value has already been computed; and if so return the previously computed value. Something like,

```
private static Map<Integer, BigInteger> memo = new HashMap<>();
static {
    memo.put(1, BigInteger.ONE);
}

public static BigInteger fact(int i) {
    if (memo.containsKey(i)) {
        return memo.get(i);
    }
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(i).multiply(fact(i - 1));
    memo.put(i, result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @ElliotFrisch thanks for your code but in recursion we use same thing as we dont get same values there is no need to check later as we go on as 4*fact(3)....can you please provide code with threads Thats what made me post here....thanks for your effort.

Comment: @SmashCode - You are wrong about that.  Memoization is used in conjunction with recursion.  Indeed, if you look are Elliott's code carefully, you will see that it >>is<< recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Elliott is correct in his comment that multi-threading is not a good way to optimize the calculation of factorials.  Certainly, it won't be effective (compared with memoization for example) until you calculate really large factorials.

In simple recursive divide and conquer strategy, the pseudo-code is

```
factorial(N) = 
    return factorialHelper(set_of(1, N))

factorialHelper(set) = 
    if set.size == 1 
       return set.first
    else
       let set1, set2 = split_into_subsets(set, 2)
       return factorialHelper(set1) * factorialHelper(set2)
```

Now we can naively use threads like this:

```
factorialHelper(set) = 
    if set.size == 1 
       return set.first
    else
       let set1, set2 = split_into_subsets(set, 2)
       return fork(lambda factorialHelper(set1)).join() *
              fork(lambda factorialHelper(set2)).join()
```

(Explanation: `fork(lambda factorialHelper(set1)).join()` is supposed to mean that we are:
   - creating a new thread to calculate `factorialHelper(set1)`,
   - starting the thread,
   - waiting for it to deliver a result.)

Here's the problem.  Each thread is doing a bunch of housekeeping (e.g. splitting the set) and then a single multiplication.  And if you look at the big picture, that means N! requires roughly N threads.

We can do better.  Rather than waiting for two subthreads to complete.  The "current" thread could do the work of one of them; e.g.

```
factorialHelper(set) = 
    if set.size == 1 
       return set.first
    else
       let set1, set2 = split_into_subsets(set, 2)
       let child = fork(lanbda factorialHelper(set1))
       return factorialHelper(set2) * child.join()
```

But that still requires roughly N / 2 threads.  And there are bigger problems:

- Creating threads is very expensive.
- Thread switching / waiting for another thread to finish is relatively expensive.
- At any given time, your computer will only run as many threads as it has physical (or hyperthread) cores.

So if you were to code the above literally in Java, it would run like a dog.  Too many threads.  Too much thread creating / switching overhead and too little *useful* work for each thread.

If you use the [Java Fork / Join Pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html), you can do a lot better, but you also need to do something about the `split_into_subsets(set, 2)` step.  That is going to do a lot of superfluous work *copying* set elements.

The classic approach would be to have a single shared array (of 1 to N) and pass "low" and "high" indexes.  But in this case we don't even need an array 'cos we know that `array[i]` is the same as `i`.  (Ignore off-by-one.  I'm still talking pseudo-code!)

But then we get to the final problem.  Balancing the workload.  The work of multiplying two large (e.g. `BigInteger`) numbers is not a constant.  It actually depends on the magnitude of the numbers.  (I think that for `M * N` it is O(log<sub>2</sub>`M` * log<sub>2</sub>`N`).  If you use naive divide and conquer, multiplications at the "left end" are much quicker than those at the "right end".   Solving this is tricky, and I suspect that divide and conquer is the wrong approach for dealing with it.

I would actually consider a hybrid approach:

- Create `T` worker threads, where `T` corresponds to the number of available cores.
- Distribute the numbers `1` through `N` into `T` subsets, in round robin fashion.
- Get each thread to (serially) calculate the product of all numbers in its subset.
- Do the final multiplies of the subset products using as many threads as possible.

At the end of the calculation, no matter how you do it, there is going to be a final multiplication that is done using one thread.  And the two calculations before that can be done by at most 2 thread.  So at the end, some thread "starvation" will be inevitable.

Finally, there is the multiplication itself.  Clearly, if we are calculating factorial(N) for big enough N for multiple threads to be worth while, the result will be larger than Long.MAX_VALUE.  Using `BigInteger` would be an obvious choice.  However, there is a bit of a question mark over `BigInteger.multiply(BigInteger)`.  It might be worthwhile to look at high performance N-digit multiplication algorithms, and multiplication algorithms that can be parallelised.  Start here:

- [Computational complexity of mathematical operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations)

For the record, the complexity of `BigInteger.multiply(BigInteger)` for two n-digit numbers is as follows:

- Java 6 uses the "school boy" algorithm; i.e the complexity is O(n*n) for n digits
- Java 8 uses the "school boy" algorithm, the Karatsuba algorithm (O(n*1.585)) or 3-way Toom–Cook multiplication (O(n*1.465)) depending on  the size of n.  So ultimately, the complexity is O(n*1.465).

Answer (score 0):

How about this code :-
1. Get input number and create pairs(start,end).
2. Create a Task which multiply given number and return results;
3. Submit the task.
4. Get the results using future.

public class TestFactorial {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,ExecutionException {


    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println(" Please enter the number for which you want to calculate Factorial");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    int number =0;
    int answer =1;
    scanner.close();
    if(input!=null)
            number = Integer.valueOf(input);
    if(number==0 || number ==1){
            answer = 1;
    }
    calcuateFactorial(number, answer);

}

private static void calcuateFactorial(int number, int answer) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<Future<Integer>> totalTaskResults = new ArrayList<Future<Integer>>();
    for(int start =1;start<=number ;start++){
        int end = start+1;
        Future<Integer> taskResult;
        if(end>start)
            taskResult = executor.submit(new Multiply(start, 1));
        else 
             taskResult=    executor.submit(new Multiply (start, end));
        totalTaskResults.add(taskResult);

    }

    for (Future<Integer> future :totalTaskResults){
        answer = answer* future.get();
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Answer "+ answer);
}
```

}

Here is the callable class (tasks) :-

```
public class Multiply implements Callable<Integer>{
private int start ;
private int end;


public Multiply (int start, int end){
    this.start= start;
    this.end = end;
}

@Override
public Multiply  call() throws Exception {
    return start*end;
}
```

}